# Writing an ISO file to flash memory

Tags: applications, usb

I have an Ubuntu DVD ISO file downloaded in my android phone. Is there any way or any app I can use to write the ISO file to a USB flash memory connected to the phone so that the flash memory can be used just like a DVD to boot into Ubuntu in a desktop computer?

Answer (score 2):

There is an app on the Play Store called 'DriveDroid' which will allow you to do exactly what it is you are looking for.

I am not sure however, if it is free or not but unfortunately you need a rooted phone to use it.

Comment: well it seems my phone cannot be rooted. I want to write the ISO to a flash memery, drivedroid tries to use the phone as a flash memory instead.

Comment: I believe this is why you need root, so that it can access and use USB or SD Card. Is there no root information for your phone on the net?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not actively maintained; [EtchDriod](https://etchdroid.depau.eu/) still a works file for Linux ISOs.

> EtchDroid is an open-source application that helps you write images to USB drives, no root required.